# Post to facebook - user hasn't authorized the application to perform this request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I am trying to setup my app, so the user can login to facebook and i can then upload a post for them, simple.

I have this code

```
// let the user login
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
        // post to facebook
        // create our facebook data object
        var data = {
            access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
            message: "Upload this post to facebook"
        };
        // success, now upload the rest of the post, text etc
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', data, function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert("There was an error uploading your post to facebook: " + response
                    .error.message);
            } else {
                alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert(
            'There was an error logging you in to facebook, or you did not authorize the app to post on your wall'
        );
    }
}, {
    scope: 'publish_stream'
});
```

Since this is a cordova app, i have this in my device ready event

```
// initialize facebook
FB.init({
    appId: "123456789",  // facebook appId
    nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
    useCachedDialogs: false
});
```

Now as you can see, i am asking for the permission "publish_stream" which i believe is correct, but i keep getting a message when attempting to post, saying

```
There was an error uploading your post to facebook (#200). The user hasn't authorizard the application to perform this request
```

Well i quite clearly have.

I have this on another application that i created nearly a year ago and it all seems to work fine.

One thing i have read about is that "publish_stream" or "publish_actions" is now not available when you login, unless you submit your app for review?  is this only for new apps created, as i havent done this with my other app, but it seems to work.  This app also shows a message after you login, shown here.  I am sure my other app doesnt show this

[image]

EDIT:
I have checked my other app and it doesnt show the above message.  here is a screenshot

[image]

Any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

- `publish_stream` is deprecated, use `publish_actions`
- before you can use publish_actions for other users, you have to go through a [login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process - or the permission will only for for users with a role in your app (Admin/Developer/Tester)

Btw, you are not allowed to prefill the message parameter, it always has to be 100% user generated. And don´t "autopost" right after login (or ever). That´s against the rules too. Check out the platform policy for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Thank you. Do apps previously created work then? This applies to newly created apps?

Comment: publish_stream is deprecated since years, not sure why so many people still try to use it. it MAY still work for older apps, but you should never use it. you can´t even select it in the graph api explorer.

Comment: Code above is just sample. When u say v2.0 is that the facebook api or v2.0 of facebook apps?

Comment: v2.0 is the facebook api - but i did not mention v2.0 ;) - publish_stream was deprecated long before v2.0.

Comment: to the downvoter: please specify why you downvoted, so i can improved my answer if necessary.